# How to Reduce UICollectionView Size

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have this UICollectionView, layout scroll direction = horizontal.

I don't want it to occupy all page (as it does when you create it in IB), I need to have a header (another view) above it. This won't work using Accessories -> Header Section, when the scrolling is horizontal this header section sits to the left of the collection view. And it's not fixed, as I need my view to be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar and ended up just putting a UIView at the top that allowed me to put whatever I needed up there.  It just solved a lot of problems for me.

I thought it was strange the way the header operates in the horizontal scrolling mode.  It isn't really a header at all.

Revision -- I don't use IB at all, so it is all hand-coded -- but either way, you can do it.  I've attached a screenshot of something I'm working on now -- it has a picker view and a youtube video at the top, where your header would be and a collection view down below.  You could, of course, make your header view whatever size you want it to be and with whatever content.  In this case I also have a footer that is a different view as well, but the concept is the same.[image]

Comment: I supposed you did that programatically? Or were you able to do it in IB? Thanks

Comment: You get that you would just reduce the size of your UICollectionView to leave space at the top for your additional "header" view area, right?

Comment: You can't reduce the size of your UICollectionView in IB

Comment: Are you using UICollectionView or UICollectionViewController?  With UICollectionView your frame size will dictate the screen region that is covered.  I seldom use any of those Controller objects; preferring instead to subclass UIViewController and put whatever views (collection, table, scroll, other) inside that VC, that way you can control the size/location of each view with its frame.  I found IB to be a little inflexible so I've done little more than tinker with it.

Comment: I'm using UICollectionViewController. I hoped I can use it with IB, but I'm really naive :) Thanks RE.

Comment: Not having used IB, I may not be much help -- but it seems to me you could use a plain UIViewController and put a UIView at the top (as the header) and a UICollectionView sized to the rest of the screen below.  Then put whatever subviews you need within the header view and you should be good to go.  That's essentially what I've done above in code.